# Cannot post data using <pre>

Tags: support

I'm trying to make a post which contains some data. To keep the formatting I wrap it in `<pre>` html tags, but the system complains that it appears to be code and refuses to accept it. The raw data looks like this (well, it's a table normally):

.      x          y
1   0.2 -0.7031864
2   0.3 -1.0533648
3   0.4 -1.3019655
4   0.5 -1.4919278

How do I post it as a table here?

Answer (score 1):

Simply paste it as a code block instead - use four spaces at the beginning of each line

```
.      x          y
1   0.2 -0.7031864
2   0.3 -1.0533648
3   0.4 -1.3019655
4   0.5 -1.4919278
```

There are some great tools online to help you format things for markdown syntax or even just to be displayed in an ascii only manner... One such tool is [this one](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) which allows you to format tables very easily. Your table would look something like this -

```
+---+-----+------------+
| . |  x  |      y     |
+---+-----+------------+
| 1 | 0.2 | -0.7031864 |
| 2 | 0.3 | -1.0533648 |
| 3 | 0.4 | -1.3019655 |
| 4 | 0.5 | -1.4919278 |
+---+-----+------------+
```